# img ng-src remember image path

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a photo on my program which I want to change, I tried few times, changed the path of-course but nothing change, the image is the old one. why? how can I change it ?

```
<div class="stickedLogo hidden-xs">
        <div class="text-left padTop20 padLft30">
            <img ng-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0sKZ.png" alt="logo" class="stickImg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks!

Comment: In what way you want to change your photo? After click or something like that?

Comment: I just want to see one image, but no matter what I change in the path' it remember the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I provided a simple working example with `ng-src` and a controller with a variable from which you can change the image and/or the name.

In one of the comments in an answer here, you said that the path of the image is: `ng-src="{{imageRoot}}{{business_folder}}/{{business_logo}}"`; I recommend you to verify if the above code results in a valid path. You can simply place the string `{{imageRoot}}{{business_folder}}/{{business_logo}}` above the `img` tag and verify if there are no missing `/` or there are `//`. There might be actually a problem in the path, and not the actual code to display the image.

Cheers!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.imageSettings = {
      name: "My cute image",
      imageURL: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cat-force/256/cat_acrobat.png"
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="stickedLogo hidden-xs">
    <div class="text-left padTop20 padLft30">
      {{ imageSettings.name }} <br>
      <img ng-src="{{ imageSettings.imageURL }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: additional info**

If the image still does not appear and the path is correct, please put the below code right after you change the path variables:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply();
}, 0);
```

Sometimes you need to force the changes to take effect. The reason is that two-way binding in angular uses dirty checking. This is a [good article](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/) to read about angular's dirty checking.  $scope.$apply() kicks off a $digest cycle. This will apply the binding. Essentially, binding happens during the $digest cycle (if the value is seen to be different).

Comment: Thnk you! will try it. actually I wrote the path to show the old path. I change it to image url but in the console I see it still refer to `{{imageRoot}}{{business_folder}}/{{business_logo}}` also changes in the css not changing. very weird. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the article too. didn't know it

Comment: Can you please post the updated code? Also, if you follow the displayed path, can you access the image? You can also check your code with simple images from the internet, instead of local ones. Can you try, please? This way we can eliminate some of the possibilities.

Comment: I changed like you said in other program(copy of the first one) and its work. how can it word in one and not in the other? same projects. thanks

Comment: Maybe it is a typo somewhere, that's a possible explanation. You can compare the sources to see that. Another one would be some browser cache errors, but it is unlikely. If my answer helped you, you can vote it and/or mark it as an accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: will try to solve it. thank you for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your image with simple function, here after click:
HTML

```
 <div>
      <button ng-click="change_image()" class="btn">Change img</button>
            <div class="text-left padTop20 padLft30">
                <img ng-src="{{image_url}}" alt="logo" class="stickImg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.image_url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0sKZ.png';

 $scope.change_image = function() {
   $scope.image_url = "https://picsum.photos/" + Math.floor(Math.random() *500);;
   console.log($scope.image_url)
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eNMsxlsfyW9xUGOmcc2P?p=preview

Comment: Still no change and remembering the old path

Comment: @Dina93 hmm, look at my code - everything works fine. Could you show me your code?

Comment: this is my code:  `<div class="stickedLogo hidden-xs">
  <div class="text-left padTop20 padLft30">
   <img ng-src="{{imageRoot}}{{business_folder}}/{{business_logo}}" alt="logo" class="stickImg">
  </div>`
 </div> when I changed the path for image link, its still remember this path, and show the image

Comment: I want it just to show the image, without any click